# How to find an exported functions' instructions in DLL

Tags: windows, debugging, dll, portable-executable, dumpbin

I have a DLL file (64-bits) and try to find the source code instructions of an exported function named **write** in it.

With the use of `DUMPBIN.EXE` I can see the exported label **write** with RVA 24A0H.

```
    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
       3 number of functions
       3 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00002140 Close = Close
      2    1 000020F0 Open = Open
      3    2 000024A0 write = write
```

This RVA resides in section `.text` of the DLL file as it is shown from the dump of the file that RVA 24A0H is between `0000000180001000 to 0000000180006628`:

```
SECTION HEADER #1
  .text name
  5629 virtual size
  1000 virtual address (0000000180001000 to 0000000180006628)
  5800 size of raw data
  400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 00005BFF)
     0 file pointer to relocation table
     0 file pointer to line numbers
     0 number of relocations
     0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
       Code
       Execute Read
```

Calculating the file offset of the **write** function has been done with

```
offset = RVA - Virtual address of the section + Pointer to raw data
offset = 24A0H - 1000H + 400H = 18A0H
```

Should I now, go to this offset from the start of DLL file to see the instructions (or byte codes) of the exported function?

Thanks.